# Apache or IIS? (or something else?)

Tags: apache-2.2, iis

IIS and Apache are the two most widely used Web servers. As [Netcraft](http://news.netcraft.com/archives/2010/06/16/june-2010-web-server-survey.html) surveys show us, Apache is still over twice as popular as IIS. But why is that so? Is that because you have to pay for IIS? Is Apache really more reliable?

Please tell me which one is the best in terms of stability, flexibility, portability, security and performance.

+ I have practically zero experience with IIS.

Comment: Do you have experience with Apache?

Comment: More or less. I use Pylons and Django for web development, and I wasn't that much worried about the web server.

Answer (score 1):

Apache is cross-platform, so it can be used on various operating systems, including Windows. In contrast, IIS is Windows-only. In addition the LAMP stack is a very common server setup...After all that, the reason for the disparity is easy to see.

Generally speaking, if you want to work with ASP.NET, you need to use IIS. Any other setup - PHP, Ruby, Perl, Python, etc - can be done on Apache, and sometimes on IIS as well. So I dare to say that unless you want to do ASP.NET, stick with Apache.

As for your criteria, I don't know how the servers compare in those regards, though both are pretty mature and stable at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, at this point, if you are more familiar with Apache, as long as Apache meets your needs, I am not sure why you'd consider IIS.